# Acumatica Error Sending SO via SOAP

Tags: vb.net, soap-client, acumatica

In trying to send an SO to Acumatica, I am getting the following error:

```
PX.Api.ContractBased.OutcomeEntityHasErrorsException: PX.Data.PXException: Error: The system failed to commit the Transactions row.
   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.a(Object A_0, PXFilterRow[] A_1, PXFilterRow[] A_2)
   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.ExportTableHelper.ExportTable()
   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.WebApiSoapController.Post(ISoapSystemContract systemContract, XmlReader requestReader, String serviceNamespace, String internalNamespace, MethodInfo method, Func`1 serviceFactory, IEdmModel edmModel)
   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.WebApiSoapController.<Post>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.WebApiSoapController.<Login>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

I am using this code to send the SO:

```
     Dim inv As SalesOrder = DirectCast(con.SoapClient.Put(BuildSO(con, trans)), SalesOrder)


 Protected Function BuildSO(con As AcumaticaConnection, inv As Transaction) As SalesOrder
        Dim out As New SalesOrder
        With inv
            out.OrderType = New StringValue With {.Value = "SO"}
            If .Customer.HasID Then out.CustomerID = New StringValue With {.Value = inv.Customer.NameString}
            If .TxnDate.HasValue Then out.Date = New DateTimeValue With {.Value = inv.TxnDate}
            If .RefNumber.HasFullName Then
                out.OrderNbr = New StringValue With {.Value = inv.RefNumber.FullName}
                out.CustomerOrder = New StringValue With {.Value = inv.RefNumber.FullName}
                out.Description = New StringValue With {.Value = inv.RefNumber.FullName}
            End If
            If .HasMemo Then out.Note = .Memo
            If .HasShipVia Then out.ShipVia = New StringValue With {.Value = inv.ShipVia}

            Dim details As New List(Of SalesOrderDetail)
            Dim lnum As Integer = 1
            For Each l As TransactionLine In inv
                Dim detail As New SalesOrderDetail
                detail.LineNbr = New IntValue With {.Value = lnum}
                lnum += 1

                detail.InventoryID = New StringValue With {.Value = l.ItemKey}
                If l.Qty <> 0 Then
                    detail.Quantity = New DecimalValue With {.Value = l.Qty}
                End If
                If l.HasUnit Then
                    detail.UOM = New StringValue With {.Value = l.UnitofMeasure}
                Else
                    detail.UOM = New StringValue With {.Value = "EA"}
                End If

                details.Add(detail)
            Next
            out.Details = details.ToArray
        End With
        Return out
    End Function
```

I have tried making sure all the fields filled out in the i210 course are filled out in my code (thus the UOM bit), but nothing I change seems to make a difference. Is there anything I can do to at least get more information about what the error might be so I can troubleshoot further?

Answer (score -1):

try adding below line after passing Order Type. and this is C# code.

inv.Actions.Insert,

Comment: There is no `Actions` property on `SalesOrder`.